# What does ヤキ入れ here?

Tags: translation, idioms

i cant find a clear translation but in the anime it is translated as   "beating someone up" or something similar. any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

焼きを入れる is an idiom meaning *to torture, to punish*. It apparently derives from blacksmiths putting metal in fire to harden it.

It often has the connotation of lynch done by delinquent kids or mafia.

> [焼きを入れる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%84%BC%E3%81%8D%E3%82%92%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B/)
>
> 2. ゆるんだ気持ちを引き締めさせる。また、制裁や拷問を加える。「後輩に―・れる」

See also [やき](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%82%84%E3%81%8D/#je-75947).